# Instantaneous rate of change

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x) = ax + b$.
>
> Find the instantaneous rate of change of $f(x)$ at the following points: $1, 2, 4\text{ and }8$.

Is the instantaneous rate of change for all the points  $a$, because the derivative for $f'(x)= a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the instantaneous rate of change is $4$.

To see this (even) more explicitly, remember that the derivative $f'(x)$ is defined as $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, so $$\frac{d}{dx} (ax+b) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(a(x+h) + b)  - (ax+b)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{ah}{h} = a$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This is now my shortest answer... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

That is right. You have a fixed rate (velocity) at all instances of $x$.